# SwiftUI "environment-dependent" Color

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-environment

In Apple's documentation, `Color` is defined as: "An ***environment-dependent*** color." (emphasis mine)

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color

Is it correct, therefore, to say that a SwiftUI Color is not constant but that the color of the Color (sic) depends upon its environment.

What would be an example of this environment dependency?

Comment: Dark/light mode would be an example.

Comment: Check here to see which colours exactly are used: https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/visual-design/color/#dynamic-system-colors

Answer (score 1):

**Dark/light mode** **is the example for environment-dependent Color**

[image: Dark/light mode]